# Expecting 404 but getting 200 HTTP status code

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, pip, python-requests

I’ve been using the following command to get the status code of a Tweet:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://twitter.com/jack/38373837")

status_code = response.status_code


print(status_code)
----------------------
200
```

I expected 404. However, I got 200.

Is there another command, or perhaps even a Python package, that accurately determines a page’s HTTP status code?

Comment: Why do you expect 404? Just because there isn't a tweet? There's still a *web page* at that URL. Did you try visiting the link in a browser, and looking at the developer tags? The response is a 200 that way, too. Every library will accurately determine the status code as 200 for this URL (assuming a working Internet connection), because the status code **is** 200. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: Dear Karl, thank you for your response. I expected 404 because I used httpstatus.io to check status codes. For example, go to https://httpstatus.io, type in the following deleted Tweet, and check its status using the Bing Bot or Yandex Bot. You'll see that either gives out a 404 error. https://twitter.com/davemeltzerWON/status/1321279214365016064

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because it actually loads Twitter and Twitter can't load the post. So the response is 200 which means OK! Cause you can reach Twitter.

If you try it with an API or with a website that has no protection, you can get error 404!

Try with "https://cidqu.net/thisisnotexist.html"

This page doesn't load anything so it will give you the error 404.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on my laptop and i got 200 as well. I used the -I to get only the headers.

```
 -I, --head          Show document info only
```

```
nabil@LAPTOP:~$ curl -I https://twitter.com/jack/38373837
HTTP/2 200
date: Mon, 31 Jan 2022 20:08:45 GMT
expiry: Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: tsa_f
set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A164365972506197722; Max-Age=34214400; Expires=Fri, 03 Mar 2023 20:08:45 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure; SameSite=None
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
x-powered-by: Express
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0
last-modified: Mon, 31 Jan 2022 20:08:45 GMT
x-frame-options: DENY
x-xss-protection: 0
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-security-policy: connect-src 'self' blob: https://*.giphy.com https://*.pscp.tv https://*.video.pscp.tv https://*.twimg.com https://api.twitter.com https://api-stream.twitter.com https://ads-api.twitter.com https://aa.twitter.com https://caps.twitter.com https://media.riffsy.com https://pay.twitter.com https://sentry.io https://ton.twitter.com https://twitter.com https://upload.twitter.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://accounts.google.com/gsi/status https://accounts.google.com/gsi/log https://app.link https://api2.branch.io https://bnc.lt wss://*.pscp.tv https://vmap.snappytv.com https://vmapstage.snappytv.com https://vmaprel.snappytv.com https://vmap.grabyo.com https://dhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://pdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://dwo3ckksxlb0v.cloudfront.net ; default-src 'self'; form-action 'self' https://twitter.com https://*.twitter.com; font-src 'self' https://*.twimg.com; frame-src 'self' https://twitter.com https://mobile.twitter.com https://pay.twitter.com https://cards-frame.twitter.com https://accounts.google.com/  https://recaptcha.net/recaptcha/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/; img-src 'self' blob: data: https://*.cdn.twitter.com https://ton.twitter.com https://*.twimg.com https://analytics.twitter.com https://cm.g.doubleclick.net https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.periscope.tv https://www.pscp.tv https://media.riffsy.com https://*.giphy.com https://*.pscp.tv https://*.periscope.tv https://prod-periscope-profile.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net https://scontent-sea1-1.xx.fbcdn.net https://*.googleusercontent.com https://imgix.revue.co; manifest-src 'self'; media-src 'self' blob: https://twitter.com https://*.twimg.com https://*.vine.co https://*.pscp.tv https://*.video.pscp.tv https://*.giphy.com https://media.riffsy.com https://dhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://pdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://dwo3ckksxlb0v.cloudfront.net; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.twimg.com https://recaptcha.net/recaptcha/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://www.google-analytics.com https://twitter.com https://app.link https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js  'nonce-NzE1OGUzMjgtYWVkZS00ZGNkLWI4ZjctNDQwYmU1ODA2NjJh'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://accounts.google.com/gsi/style https://*.twimg.com; worker-src 'self' blob:; report-uri https://twitter.com/i/csp_report?a=O5RXE%3D%3D%3D&ro=false
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin-allow-popups
cross-origin-embedder-policy: unsafe-none
x-response-time: 185
x-connection-hash: d1535e6f6d60a343d5d9adfbe574b67f65b771b35fcc93c7ea887705bffb2ba8
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this endpoint to check tweet if exists or not:**

```
import requests
import json

# https://twitter.com/jack/status/1247616214769086465
tweet_id = 1247616214769086465

url = 'https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/_iJccJ-mHcyaV0nq_odmBA/TweetDetail'

# Request Headers
headers = {'Host': 'twitter.com',
           'sec-ch-ua': '',
           'x-twitter-client-language': 'en',
           'x-csrf-token': '9d2d0361bd589118ff41e56619327537',
           'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
           'authorization': 'Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuH5E6I8xnZz4puTs'
                            '%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA',
           'content-type': 'application/json',
           'x-guest-token': '1488257541251469319',
           'x-twitter-active-user': 'yes',
           'sec-ch-ua-platform': '',
           'accept': '*/*',
           'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
           'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
           'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
           'referer': 'https://twitter.com/GioCellRed/status/1488257200195842048',
           'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
           'cookie': 'guest_id_ads=v1%3A164069712670696178; guest_id=v1%3A164069712670696178; '
                     'guest_id_marketing=v1%3A164069712670696178; personalization_id=',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.76'}

# Request Parameters
variables = {"focalTweetId": tweet_id, "referrer": "search",
             "controller_data": "DAACDAAFDAABDAABDAABCgABAAAAAAAAgEAAAAwAAgoAAQAAAAAAAAAICgACTOJ7aVQ"
                                "/L38LAAMAAAAFU29uaWEMAAQMAAELAAEAAAAFU29uaWELAAIAAAAkOTUxYmYyZjItMDl"
                                "hNC00ZTlmLWJkZWItMTBhYTFjMmU5YjBhAAAKAAUbtNSIOd+CdQAAAAAA",
             "with_rux_injections": False,
             "includePromotedContent": True,
             "withCommunity": True,
             "withQuickPromoteEligibilityTweetFields": True,
             "withBirdwatchNotes": False,
             "withSuperFollowsUserFields": True,
             "withDownvotePerspective": False,
             "withReactionsMetadata": False,
             "withReactionsPerspective": False,
             "withSuperFollowsTweetFields": True,
             "withVoice": True, "withV2Timeline": False,
             "__fs_interactive_text": False,
             "__fs_responsive_web_uc_gql_enabled": False,
             "__fs_dont_mention_me_view_api_enabled": False}

params = {'variables': json.dumps(variables)}

with requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params) as resp:
    result = resp.json()
    print('Error:', ("errors" in result),
          '\nSuccess:', ("data" in result))
```